# Change the background color of the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a select object and I'm trying to change the background color of the selected option. 
So when I select the option "green", the background color has to be changed to green (color information to be taken from the attribute data-color)

The following works but it's not considering attribute data-color and uses just one color (red). I'm fine with a jQuery solution or pure CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/tomsx/y3ofg0m7/

```
<select id="colors" size="5" style="height:80px;width:100px">
 <option value="1" data-color="red">red</option>
 <option value="2" data-color="green">green</option>
 <option value="3" data-color="yellow" >yellow</option>
</select>

select:focus option:checked {
  background: red linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, red 100%);
}
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms#Dealing_with_the_select_nightmare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("select#colors").change(function () {
  var $thisMenu = $(this);
  $thisMenu.children("option").css("background", "");
  var $thisOption = $thisMenu.children("option:selected");
  var color = $thisOption.data("color");
  $thisOption.css("background", "linear-gradient(0deg, "+ color +" 0%, "+ color +" 100%)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="colors" class="colors2" size="5" style="height:80px;width:100px">
 <option value="1" data-color="red">red</option>
 <option value="2" data-color="green">green</option>
 <option value="3" data-color="yellow" >yellow</option>
</select>
```

This works but it changes the colors permanently when selected.  Is this what you want or do you want the color to be lost when another option is selected?

Comment: Thank you. However, the color has to be changed as soon as an option gets selected. This is not the case in your example. The background color has to be set to "none" when another option is selected.

Comment: When you refer to the "background color", do you mean the background color of the option or of the entire menu?

Comment: The color of an option

Comment: Looks better but the the background color has to be set to "none" when another option is selected. Just the selected option must change its color.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I forgot that.  I made another change.  Sorry about the back and forth.